# Как получить число (стоимость) за минусом скидки в произвольных полях вордпреса?

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Вордпресс, плагин Advanced Custom Fields
Есть 2 доп. поля - Стоимость и Скидка
В стоимости - число
В скидки - число с процентом (напрмиер - 15%)

Я пытаюсь из этих данных получить стоимость с учетом указанной скидки:

```
<p>Стоимость : <?php echo esc_html( get_field('prices') ); ?> руб.</p>
<p>Скидка: <?php echo esc_html( get_field('skidka') ); ?></p>
<p>Итоговая цена с учетом скидки: <b>КАК ЕЕ ВЫВЕСТИ ТУТ?</b></p>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено...
Может кому пригодится

```
<p>Итоговая цена: <b><?php echo get_field('prices') - (get_field('prices') * (get_field('skidka') / 100)); ?></b></p>
```